# Query String converts space to ? (symbol) in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, request.querystring

I have an aspx web forms application developed in C#. Now the web page are being called from other application with query string parameter.

Now the issue is, when the query string parameter value is "Test example(1111) - test user" then when we access it into code, it is converting it to "Test example(1111)�- test user".

I have tried with the below options, but still it is not working

1. HttpUtility.UrlEncode
2. Server.UrlEncode

Is there anyway I can remove the symbol?

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet so we will be better able to help you.  Are you always getting the same position after the conversion?

Comment: Show your code what you have tried so far

Comment: are you using firefox?

Comment: No, I am using IE

Comment: what is the return string after encoding?

Answer (score 0):

this � symbol is know as REPLACEMENT CHARACTER it shows when `UTF-8` if trying to encode special character which might be invalid and if you try to encode

```
"Test example(1111)�- test user"
```

it will give result like

```
Test+example(1111)%ef%bf%bd-+test+user
```

you can try something like this

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query,Encoding.UTF8).Replace("%ef%bf%bd","+");
```

to get `Test+example(1111)+-+test+user`